# a dll export potential error

Tags: c++, windows

I exported a class inherited from `std::string` out of a dll.
I used it in another project, but there is a compilation error

> Error 5 error LNK2005: "public: __cdecl std::basic_string,class std::allocator >::~basic_string,class std::allocator >(void)" (??1?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAA@XZ) already defined in tps_frame.obj J:\ciplan_workstation\build\app\tpsUtilsd.lib(tpsUtilsd.dll)

I am not sure the problem was caused by the dll or lib. Until now, I have not found out the reason.

The code as following:

```
// line_string.h
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
class __declspec(dllexport) line_string : public std::string
{
     friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, line_string& str);
     public:
     inline operator std::string&() { return *this; }
};

 // line_string.cpp
 #include "line_string.h"
 std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, line_string& str)
 {
     std::getline(is, static_cast<std::string&>(str));
     return is;
 }
```

Comment: Probably caused by inconsistent linkage to standard libraries (e.g. a .lib file built for dynamic linkage vs .dll built for static linkage). Check your use of /MT vs /MD linker switches.

Comment: I have check that this is not the reason.

Comment: I replaced the inheritance from std::string with a std::string member, the problem was solved, although the original problem is still unfixed.